# random nonsingular matrices using matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab, random

Does anybody know how to generate a random nonsingular matrices using matlab? I use sprand (m, n , dens, 1)function to specify the condition number to be 1 right now.But it is too slow.Is there any command through which we can generate a random nonsingular matrices? Thank you very much!

Comment: What about `N*(expm(i*H))` where `H` is symmetric? Take `R=rand(n)` then `H=R+R'`. sorry for the comment-mess...

Comment: Also rand(n) and randn(n) will give nonsingular matrices with probability 1 (even the condition numbers will be not very large.).